# Existence of a special vector field on Riemannian manifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, vector-fields, lie-derivative

In a Riemannian Manifold $(M,g)$ a vector field $X$ is said to be Killing vector field if $L_X g$=0 and is said to be conformal if $L_X g= fg$ for some smooth real function $f$ on $M$.

Also, the notion of bi-Killing vector field is defined (in which we have $L_X (L_X g)=0$. So it is natural to define bi-conformal vector field as $L_X (L_X g)=fg$. The second Lie derivative of such vector field is proportional to the metric tensor.

But, I need to find a vector field $X\in \mathcal{X}M $ in a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ such that the second Lie derivative be proportional to $X$, in fact

> Is there exist a vector field $X$ such that $L_X (L_X g)=\lambda X^\flat \otimes X^\flat$?

Where, $\lambda$ is a real non-zero constant.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: By $X^\flat$ I mean the dual 1-form associated to $X$ by $g(X,.)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Jose Carlos Thank you for your guidance.